# RabbitMQ and Erlang on 64-bit

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I downloaded RabbitMQ 3.6.6 server exe installation file for Windows. There appears to be only one file which does not tell me if it is 32-bit version or 64-bit version. I want to run RabbitMQ on 64-bit. What kind of Erlang do I need for RabbitMQ, the 64-bit or 32-bit??
Also, if I wanted to run RabbitMQ on 64-bit Linux, what kind of Erlang do I need, the 32-bit or 64-bit? Is RabbitMQ specific to 32-bit and 64-bit ??
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/32-bit-or-64-bit-RabbitMQ-td17197.html) RabbitMQ is platform independent bytecode.

For Windows (as I use Windows 10 x64 for RabbitMQ and Erlang), both 32 and 64 bit version of Erlang/OTP will work (as long as RabbitMQ can locate the Erlang folder installation).

Comment: thank you. Is there only one flavour of RabbitMQ, i.e. there is no separate 32-bit and 64-bit edition? Does it make any difference what Erlang I use with RabbitMQ - 32-bit or 64-bit??

Comment: Correct, RabbitMQ is platform independent bytecode (source [here](http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/32-bit-or-64-bit-RabbitMQ-td17197.html)) and as you can see [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.6.6/), there is only 1 exe available. Also, it looks like it's the case for Linux as well.

Comment: thanks. Using it on Windows only for dev/learning. We run prod on Linux but I am totally new to RabbitMQ hence my questions re 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: For Linux, it will depend the architecture/distribution you are using : Debian, Suse, etc...